# Standard error question. Why can't this be equal to 1?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, standard-error

So I've been working on this question related to standard error and I managed to show that it can't be less than $1$. But how do you show that this has to be greater than $1$ (as in cannot equal $1$)?

$$ \frac{\hat{\text{SE}}_1 + \hat{\text{SE}}_2}{\sqrt{\hat{\text{SE}}_1^2 + \hat{\text{SE}}_2^2}} $$

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how did you show that it could not be less than $1$? Please edit the question to show us exactly what you've tried and where you're getting stuck. Here's a helpful reference for [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) that might help with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely an algebra question. You may take $a:=\hat{\operatorname{SE}}_1>0$ and $b:=\hat{\operatorname{SE}}_2>0$. Then this expression becomes $$\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}}>1.$$

Comment: Can't standard error be equal to 0 though?

Comment: In practice, se can never be zero. It is really rare (almost impossible) to get a data set consisting of equal observations. Note that se is the square root of variance, which is calculated as $\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$ and equals $0$ if and only if all observations are the same.